# d3js merged line/bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot an "average line" - over a multi-series group chart.

I've plotted a line that matches the series data - but I am running into a couple of issues with this hybrid.

[image]

1) plotting just an average line that cuts over the multi-series

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/276/

//plotting on same groupbar chart

```
//draw prev line

    //previous line
var prevdata = [{
          "State": "a",
          "AA": 50,
          "BB": 250
        }, {
          "State": "b",
          "AA": 314,
          "BB": 150
        },{
          "State": "c",
          "AA": 121,
          "BB": 450
        }, {
          "State": "d",
          "AA": 114,
          "BB": 150
        }];

var keys1 = d3.keys(prevdata[0]).slice(1);

var newData1 = keys1.map(function(id) {
  return {
    id: id,
    values: prevdata.map(function(d) {
      return {
        State: d.State,
        value: d[id]
      };
    })
  };
});


// define the line
var valueline = d3.line()
  .curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x(function(d) {
    return x0(d.State);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });


g.selectAll(".line")
  .data(newData1)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
  console.log("d", d)
    return valueline(d.values);
  })
  .style("stroke", function(d) {
    return "black";    
    //return z(d.id);
  });


///
```

//updating

```
//update prev line
g.selectAll('.line path').transition().duration(500)
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      if (filtered.indexOf(d.id) > -1) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return valueline(d.values);
      }
    });
```

Comment: I decided to just delete my answer, I really don't like questions that ask about different issues. It was my mistake trying to answer one of them. So, as an advice for your future questions: please keep **just one issue** per question.

Comment: Hello @GerardoFurtado -- well my question really is generating just 1 line on this as an average plot. I think the other parts are just questions in term of possible concerns in jamming the look/meaning or animation itself

Comment: In that case, edit it. I'm seeing 3 questions right now.

Comment: done - the animation transition appears to work, and the displacement to hit mid points has been addressed at least considered. - So would it just be a case of refactoring the prev line data to produce just an average value - treat it as 1 series?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado there is a bounty here man https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46700389/d3-js-curved-line-charts-with-toggle-legends

Comment: I just gave it an "average" line -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/287/

Comment: ^ but the displacement may be wrong - because its no longer got the same id's as the group chart